# update one column twice in a data.table efficient in R

Tags: r, performance, data.table, dplyr, readability

I have a data table that looks like this:

```
DT <- data.table(Zeit = c(0.024, 0.4, 0.05),
                 Gier = c(1, 2, 3),
                 GierVZ = c(1, 0, 1),
                 Quer = c(2, 4, 6))
```

Now I want to update and add some columns to this data table. But I am not able to update `Gier` twice because it would create a duplicate and get an error.

```
DT[, ':='(Zeit   = round(Zeit, digits = 2),
          Gier   = replace(Gier, Gier == 163.83, NA),
          GierVZ = factor(GierVZ, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("positiv", "negativ")),
          Quer   = Quer * 9.81,
          Gier   = ifelse(GierVZ == "negativ", Gier * -1, Gier))]
```

How can I avoid this in general and still create some readable fast code?
I am sure there is an easy answer to this. But I am kind of a newbie to data tables and I think (at least at the moment) it is not that intuitive like dplyr, but it is much faster for my big data.

Comment: Doesn't `Gier = ifelse(GierVZ == "negativ", replace(Gier, Gier == 163.83, NA)* -1, replace(Gier, Gier == 163.83, NA)))` get the Job done?

Comment: It does, but is it a good way to do it like this? What if you want to change the column a third time? What if you want to do some more stuff with one column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could evaluate `Gier` in curly braces:

```r
DT[, ':='(Zeit   = round(Zeit, digits = 2),
          Gier   = {Gier[Gier == 163.83] <- NA; ifelse(GierVZ, -Gier, Gier)},
          GierVZ = factor(GierVZ, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("positiv", "negativ")),
          Quer   = Quer * 9.81)]
```

Comment: nice solution! Is it possible to create a new column `Gier2` to create a new column `Gier3` based on `Gier2` like `Gier3 = log(Gier2)`?

Comment: Opposed to `dplyr` where you can refer to a newly created variable within a `mutate` call, `data.table` does not allow you to do that, AFAIK. You could calculate Gier2 and Gier3 separately in {} (rather inefficient), or chain [] brackets, which is equivalent to doing one step at a time (often helps readability; see first approach taken by @MichaelChirico). Generally, I would just create variables required downstream, so if you ultimately need `Gier = {Gier[Gier == 163.83] <- NA; log(ifelse(GierVZ, -Gier, Gier));}` just generate that.

Answer (score 4):

This approach has roughly the same level of readability to me & accomplishes your goal:

```
DT[ , `:=`(
  Zeit = round(Zeit, digits=2L),
  GierVZ = factor(GierVZ, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("positiv", "negativ")),
  Quer   = Quer * 9.81
)]
DT[Gier == 163.83, Gier := NA]
DT[ , Gier := fifelse(GierVZ == "negativ", Gier * -1, Gier))]
```

Alternatively, in the development version of `data.table` ([Installation instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)), you could benefit from `fcase`:

```
DT[ , `:=`(
  Zeit   = round(Zeit, digits=2L),
  GierVZ = factor(GierVZ, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("positiv", "negativ")),
  Quer   = Quer * 9.81
  Gier   = fcase(
      Gier == 163.83    , NA_real_, 
    GierVZ == 'negative',    -Gier, 
    GierVZ == 'positiv' ,     Gier
  )
)]
```

It would be easier if you could skip writing out the last `GierVZ=='positiv'` condition; this is a feature request in progress.

Comment: I like your solution! But I get an error: `could not find function "fcase"`although I updated and loaded the newest version of data.table

Comment: @Bolle it's not available on CRAN. See the link. Hopefully the following works: `install.packages('data.table', type = 'source', repos = 'http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table')`

Comment: installing the package like this works great! thank you :) But the code fcase is not working because of the different types. argument 4 is of type double, argument 2 is of type logical. It seems to work like fifelse ;)

Comment: oh right. I've fixed the answer, thanks @Bolle. another pending feature request actually :)

Comment: there is also another problem. I tried your code with the fcase. If you use this approach for example Gier = 2, all values of Gier are NA and not only the value 2